# How to prevent "MainActivity screen "display

Tags: android

I have an Android app in which the first screen is a menu display. Before it gets to the menu display though it displays a page with the launcher icon and "Main Activity" at the top. How do I prevent this display? Manifest file has this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.menu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

--- edit

So the class that displayed the menu was called MainActivity.java. Maybe not a good idea, if only because it is not a good practice. So I renamed it to MenuActivity.java and changed the manifest accordingly(below). But the behavior is still the same.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/menu_activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm understanding is that you don't want the ActionBar to appear at all in your MenuActivity. Since your target API is 11, you can add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"` to the Activity Declaration.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/menu_activity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
```

Comment: A-C: thanks for your suggestion, that did it with one note ...  the ">" needs to be after the android:theme statement.

Comment: @numberwang I was wondering why I wasn't getting syntax highlighting for that line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.menu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".YourCustomActivity"
        android:label="@string/custom_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: The class that displayed the menu was called MainActivity.java. So I renamed it to MenuActivity.java and changed the manifest accordingly, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: If your activity name is YourCustomActivity then it will be the manifest: android:name=".YourCustomActivity So if your activity name is ManiActivity then it will be android:name=".ManiActivity", also check the package name is correct or not. Try to clean your project